# Is there anyway only minify less and react components for node_modules with webpack without bundling them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, node-modules

I'm creating a node_modules package with many React components that can be installed into node_modules folder later on, each component has got a few import **js** and **less**...

I'd like to minify each component separately, make it es5 module exported to be used in react-app separately, minify them separately (both javascript and less) without bundling imported modules from npm (they stay required)...

I tried some ways which kind of working, but any good way to stop webpack bundling? how the `webpack.config.js` gonna look like in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You could export webpack config as an array of configs for each modules:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    entry: './src/apple',
    mode: 'production',
    output: {
      library: 'apple',
      libraryTarget: 'umd',
      filename: 'apple.min.js',
    },
  },
  {
    entry: './src/orange',
    mode: 'production',
    output: {
      library: 'orange',
      libraryTarget: 'umd',
      filename: 'orange.min.js',
    },
  },
];
```

Note this is a webpack 4 example, but previous versions also allow an array (they don't have`mode` though). If there is shared config you can of course spread/merge in shared parts for each item.

Comment: Thanks @Dominic Tobias, but this still bundle it with imported file into js files, imagine we import a from "abc" in apple.js, I want it be required, but not bundled... read from node_modules or if not, put it in a shared folder, you still use' [name].min.js' for multiple entries